# How fine-grained should tags be?

Tags: discussion, tags

StackOverflow is constantly battling tag-granularity issues. Things like [jquery-ui](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) vs [jquery](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery), etc.

How fine-grained should CG.SE's tags be?

- [buffer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer) vs [depth-buffer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depth-buffer) + [stencil-buffer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stencil-buffer) + ...
- [shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shader) vs [fragment-shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fragment-shader) + [vertex-shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertex-shader) / [hlsl-shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hlsl-shader) + [glsl-shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glsl-shader)

What is the authoritative answer on this?

Answer (score 7):

It's tough to make a hard decision on this at the moment. We can't really anticipate yet what the question landscape around here is going to look like and it probably depends a lot on that.

For now I'd suggest using a finer granularity. Separate tags for separate shader stages definitely make sense. We can always create synonyms or burninate tags later on. My general opinion on tagging is that there's a reason a question can have up to 5 tags. As long as we don't run into trouble adding all applicable tags within this limit, I think more is better, because it allows for more effective filtering of questions.

Comment: Fair enough, will do.